# regex query for filenames with multiple numbers at the beginning of the filename

Tags: regex, bash, zsh, filenames

I am trying to create a regex query. I need the regex query to extract filenames from a directory.

I will run the regex query via a bash/shell script

It is important that only files are found which have several "article numbers" at the beginning of the file. e. g.: `123456_654321_test_testing-tags1-tags2.jpg`

The file name may contain underscores and hyphens as separators.
The file extensions are as follows = `(jpg|tif|zip|mp4|psd|eps|flv|mov|png|mp3|bnl|pdf)`

So far, I have created the following regex query via a regex tester, but this does not work as I thought it would. I don't really understand how it works with the capturing groups.

`([[:digit:]]{2,})+([_])+([[:alnum:]]{3,})+`

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @CharchitKapoor Sorry, I didn't think to add it. I have edited the post again.

Comment: try this https://regex101.com/r/zRnZLB/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
\d+_\d+[\w-]*\.(?:jpg|tif|zip|mp4|psd|eps|flv|mov|png|mp3|bnl|pdf)
```

Comment: Wow! I didn't think it would work with such a short query. I quickly tested it and it seems to work exactly as I imagined. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.  The _Wikipedia_ article on _[regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)_ is a good source, if you're unfamiliar with the syntax.